# The 2-norm of matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

If A is nonsingular, then there exists a singular matrix B such that $||B-A||_2=||A^{-1}||_2$

I tried Orthogonal decomposition,but failed.  Could anybody give me some hints?

Any assistance will be appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure about the expression? I think it should be $\|B-A\| = \frac{1}{\|A^{-1}\|}$.

Comment: I think you are right.l disproved this question when n=2,my book gives me a wrong conclusion...

Comment: It is easy to check that if $A$ invertible and $B$ is singular, we must have 
$$
\|A-B\| \ge \frac{1}{\|A^{-1}\|}.
$$

If fact, since $B$ is singular, there is some vector $v$, with $\|v\| = 1$ such that $Bv=0$. So,
$$
\|A-B\| = \sup_{x\ne 0} \frac{\|(A-B)x\|}{\|x\|} \ge \frac{\|(A-B)v\|}{\|v\|} = \|Av\| \ge \frac{\|v\|}{\|A^{-1}\|} = \frac{1}{\|A^{-1}\|}
$$

Comment: This exercise shows the the set of invertible matrices is open.